# My Samsung TV won't respond to some UPNP XML requests to describe its service

Tags: networking, soap, network-programming, upnp, service-discovery

I've been reading this UPNP PDF and it says that when a device enters the network, it sends a SSDP message with its LOCATION, which is an address that will describe its services. When I turn my Samsung Smart TV on, I get around 6 or 7 SSDP messages. One of them is the following:

```
NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1800
LOCATION: http://192.168.1.107:7676/smp_7_
NT: upnp:rootdevice
NTS: ssdp:alive
SERVER: SHP, UPnP/1.0, Samsung UPnP SDK/1.0
USN: uuid:uuid_here::upnp:rootdevice
```

So when I try to connect to the LOCATION in this SSDP message, I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns='urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0' xmlns:sec='http://www.sec.co.kr/dlna' xmlns:dlna='urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0'>
 <specVersion>
  <major>1</major>
  <minor>0</minor>
 </specVersion>
 <device>
  <deviceType>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:device:dialreceiver:1</deviceType>
  <friendlyName>[TV]Samsung LED40</friendlyName>
  <manufacturer>Samsung Electronics</manufacturer>
  <manufacturerURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</manufacturerURL>
  <modelDescription>Samsung TV NS</modelDescription>
  <modelName>UN40HU7000</modelName>
  <modelNumber>1.0</modelNumber>
  <modelURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</modelURL>
  <serialNumber>serialNumberHere</serialNumber>
  <UDN>uuid:uuid_here</UDN>
  <sec:deviceID>EXCNHA5ILPT66</sec:deviceID>
  <sec:ProductCap>Resolution:1920X1080,Y2014</sec:ProductCap>
  <serviceList>
   <service>
    <serviceType>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1</serviceType>
    <serviceId>urn:dial-multiscreen-org:serviceId:dial</serviceId>
    <controlURL>/smp_9_</controlURL>
    <eventSubURL>/smp_10_</eventSubURL>
    <SCPDURL>/smp_8_</SCPDURL>
   </service>
  </serviceList>
  <sec:Capabilities>
   <sec:Capability name='samsung:multiscreen:1' port='8001' location='/ms/1.0/'></sec:Capability>
  </sec:Capabilities>
 </device>
</root>
```

The UPNP PDF says that I must connect to the controlURL in the service described above, but when i GET http://192.168.1.107/smp_9_ I get no response. It simply does not respond. I though it was something related to the service being not activated at the moment, but for example, [this post](http://sc0ty.pl/tag/samsung/) teaches how to send a SOAP message to the RenderingControl1 service to change the volume. This service should be active when I'm using the TV to watch something. So I tried to respond to the SSDP message related to RenderingControl1:

```
NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=1800
LOCATION: http://192.168.1.107:7676/smp_3_
NT: urn:samsung.com:device:RemoteControlReceiver:1
NTS: ssdp:alive
SERVER: SHP, UPnP/1.0, Samsung UPnP SDK/1.0
USN: uuid:uuid_here::urn:samsung.com:device:RemoteControlReceiver:1
```

When I `GET 192.168.1.107:7676/smp_3_` the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns='urn:schemas-upnp-org:device-1-0' xmlns:sec='http://www.sec.co.kr/dlna' xmlns:dlna='urn:schemas-dlna-org:device-1-0'>
 <specVersion>
  <major>1</major>
  <minor>0</minor>
 </specVersion>
 <device>
  <deviceType>urn:samsung.com:device:RemoteControlReceiver:1</deviceType>
  <friendlyName>[TV]Samsung LED40</friendlyName>
  <manufacturer>Samsung Electronics</manufacturer>
  <manufacturerURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</manufacturerURL>
  <modelDescription>Samsung TV RCR</modelDescription>
  <modelName>UN40HU7000</modelName>
  <modelNumber>1.0</modelNumber>
  <modelURL>http://www.samsung.com/sec</modelURL>
  <serialNumber>serialNumberHere</serialNumber>
  <UDN>uuid:uuid_here</UDN>
  <sec:deviceID>EXCNHA5ILPT66</sec:deviceID>
  <sec:ProductCap>Resolution:1920X1080,ImageZoom,ImageRotate,Y2014,ENC</sec:ProductCap>
  <serviceList>
   <service>
    <serviceType>urn:samsung.com:service:MultiScreenService:1</serviceType>
    <serviceId>urn:samsung.com:serviceId:MultiScreenService</serviceId>
    <controlURL>/smp_5_</controlURL>
    <eventSubURL>/smp_6_</eventSubURL>
    <SCPDURL>/smp_4_</SCPDURL>
   </service>
  </serviceList>
  <sec:Capabilities>
   <sec:Capability name='samsung:multiscreen:1' port='8001' location='/ms/1.0/'></sec:Capability>
  </sec:Capabilities>
 </device>
</root>
```

but when I try to `GET 192.168.1.107:7676/smp_5_` I also get no response. I also tried to `GET 192.168.1.107:7676/smp_3_/smp_5_` because /smp_5_ is a 'subset' of /smp_3_ I get BAD Request, which tells that my TV is ignoring /smp_5_ but explictly tells that /smp_3_/smp_5_ is wrong, so /smp_3_ is quite rigth, but I don['t know what's happening. According to the UPNP PDF, 
`GET 192.168.1.107:7676/smp_5_` should retrieve the description for the service... How to get the description of the RenderingControl?

Comment: As noted by Willings, there are plenty of open source UPnP libraries which will handle all aspects of the protocol for you.  You'd be much faster using one of them.  Searching SO for "UPnP library" + your preferred language name should point you towards appropriate libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to UPnP Specification,

`http://192.168.1.107:7676/smp_7_` from `SSDP` is called `DeviceDescription` URL, so you could get XML via HTTP `GET`

while URLs in

```
<controlURL>/smp_9_</controlURL>
<eventSubURL>/smp_10_</eventSubURL>
<SCPDURL>/smp_8_</SCPDURL>
```

`http://192.168.1.107:7676/smp_9_` is control URL, you need to do `SOAP` action with HTTP Post and necessary parameters.

`http://192.168.1.107:7676/smp_10_` is event subscription URL, but you need to do `SUBSCRIBE` with necessary parameters not `GET`.

`http://192.168.1.107:7676/smp_8_` is `ServiceDescription` URL, you can do `GET` and get XML file.

More in: http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf

Comment: But which parameters? Can't see no one, that's why I thougth this service should be described

Comment: You need to read UPnP Specification in detail although it's a little complicated. Or you could use some UPnP Library to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. Maybe it will prove useful. It is the decompiled source for the Smart View windows application

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4rFn8xXaiKsZ3lCNFBpcklDRE0